# rails dev log output - how can I stop the GETs for subsequent assets (e.g. javascript, images) getting logged?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

In Ruby on Rails, in terms of the development logging (i.e. what you see in the console) - how can I stop the GETs for subsequent assets (e.g. javascript, images) getting logged?   That is, all the subsequent GET's that occur after the main action is called.

For each valid interaction I get a heap of lines like the following that would be good not to have to see...

> Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 10.1.1.1 at 2012-02-21
>   09:42:46 +1000 Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been a hotly debated issue on the Rails GitHub issues page.

see: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2639

Basically you can hide any logs related to Sprockets using the following config value

`config.assets.logger = false`

But this won't actually hide the `GET` requests in the development log (see [Jose Valim's explanation](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3795#issuecomment-3549669))

To fully hide *all* asset messages, use the patch described [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2639#issuecomment-3635046).